# lircd works when run from command line, not when run from init.d/service

Tags: command-line, mythbuntu, lirc

I'm configuring a system for use as a media centre, running Mythbuntu 12.04. Everything is working, short of the remote. I've configured my remote, and it I start lirc from the command line, it works fine. If I run it from the init script `service lirc start` it doesn't work. (For this purpose, work means to have irw show an output). In both cases I'm using exactly the same command (in fact, for running it from the command line, I'm just copying the command that is present in `ps -ef`). Both cases have lirc running as root (at least that's what `ps -ef` tells me). Both cases produce exactly the same info in syslog.

Command to start lirc:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lircd --output=/var/run/lirc/lircd --driver=devinput --device=/dev/input/irremote
```

syslog output (start lirc, start irw, stop irw, kill lirc):

```
Aug 13 22:06:05 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: lircd(devinput) ready, using /var/run/lirc/lircd
Aug 13 22:06:05 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
Aug 13 22:06:05 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: initializing '/dev/input/irremote'
Aug 13 22:06:28 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: accepted new client on /var/run/lirc/lircd
Aug 13 22:06:35 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: removed client
Aug 13 22:06:42 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: caught signal
Aug 13 22:06:42 Myth-FJ lircd-0.9.0[4917]: closing '/dev/input/irremote'
```

I'm completely stumped.

Comment: Do you use `sudo` for `service lirc start`?

Comment: @Braiam: Yes; the service starts and runs correctly

Comment: so, you forgot to add sudo before service?

Comment: @Braiam: no; I start the service with sudo. If I didn't, it wouldn't start, as a normal user would lack the permissions. Besides which, I stated in my post that lirc is running as root in both cases. EDIT: to clarify, when I said "the service starts and runs correctly", it starts, and doesn't show any errors, but doesn't produce any useful output to irw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same symptoms, **lirc** would not work when run as a service, but would work as a command. Note that in my case some of the keys worked, but only when lirc was not running (neither as a service nor a command).

The problem was that **evdev** (an input driver for **Xorg**) was picking up the remote as a keyboard input device. Getting **evdev** to ignore the remote solved the problem for me. I guess that the **lirc** service start script got hung up by the fact that **evdev** had a handle on the remote, somehow.

The problem is detailed in this thread: http://www.tbsdtv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=2896&sid=f8d407bf0e7a02db70439a41ea2adc3c

The following is from the last post in that thread. Note: TBS6981 is the satellite tuner which I was using as my remote receiver.

> The problem was caused by **evdev** (an input driver for Xorg) which was picking up the remote as a keyboard input device. This could be seen from my Xorg logs (/var/log/Xorg...), see below. Most of the buttons don't work by default because they don't naturally map to keyboard buttons, e.g. your keyboard doesn't have an **EPG** key, but it does have numbers and direction keys.
>
> There are basically two solutions
>
> 1. Configure evdev to ignore the IR input and use lirc OR
> 2. Remap the remote buttons to keyboard keys, as discussed in [this post](http://www.tbsdtv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=7749#p25232), and don't use lirc
>
> **evdev** can be configured to ignore the TBS6981 as a keyboard by adding the following to the end of */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf* -
>
> ```
> Section "InputClass"
>         Identifier "cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981)"
>         MatchProduct "cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981)"
>         MatchIsKeyboard "on"
>         Option "Ignore"
> EndSection
> ```
>
> Note that **MatchProduct** above matches the identifier found in *Xorg.0.log*.
>
> This is an extract from Xorg.0.log showing evdev picking the remote input, these lines do not appear if evdev is correctly configured to ignore the remote as a keyboard:
>
> ```
> [    21.486] (II) config/udev: Adding input device cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981) (/dev/input/event3)
> [    21.486] (**) cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
> [    21.486] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981)'
> [    21.486] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
> [    21.486] (**) cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): always reports core events
> [    21.486] (**) evdev: cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): Device: "/dev/input/event3"
> [    21.486] (--) evdev: cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): Vendor 0x6981 Product 0x8888
> [    21.486] (--) evdev: cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): Found keys
> [    21.486] (II) evdev: cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981): Configuring as keyboard
> [    21.486] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/0000:02:00.0/rc/rc0/input3/event3"
> [    21.486] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "cx23885 IR (TurboSight TBS 6981)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
> ```

So, first step is look for lines in your */var/log/Xorg.0.log* showing **evdev** picking up your remote receiver, then configure 
*/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf* to ignore the receiver using the id for the receiver as found in *Xorg.0.log*.